# How to tell when Rails app is activated by migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a migration for my app, and in this app I'm using a gem that tries to startup a different service upon app startup. Apparently, creating a migration...

```
rails generate migration AddSomeStuffToTable stuff:string
```

...activates the app, and this gem which tries to connect to startup the service. It appears that starting up the app via generating a migration makes the service startup unable to connect, so it just keeps sleeping and trying again, never actually running the migration.

In this gem, I've already dealt with this for rake, so this is what I've got so far:

```
MyService.start unless defined? Rake or defined? IRB
```

This handles the rake problem (like rake db:migrate, rake db:populate), but how can I handle the creation of migration, which (as far as I know) is not a Rake task?

Comment: Did you consider creating migration file manually? Or this is pure curiosity? :)

Comment: Well that would be an alternative, but I really feel like I should be able to use rails generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using environment variables for disabling the service:

```
MyService.start unless ENV['NO_SERVICE']
```

And run your command like this:

```
NO_SERVICE=1 rails generate migration AddSomeStuffToTable stuff:string
```

However, I doubt this scales well, especially if multiple developers are in the app. A better approach might be to do the reverse of this, to only start the service if a particular env variable *is* present. However, going this direction, you'd need to make sure your app servers set this variable, for example:

Apache: `SetEnv START_SERVICE 1`

nginx: `env START_SERVICE=1`

thin: `START_SERVICE=1 thin start`

Comment: The reverse approach definitely seems to be the way to go in this project. Thanks for the help!